# Outdoor Event - D80 lenses

Tags: lens

Ola there, can someone help me with lens suggestions for an Outodoor (bright, booths, performances) event - D80 - on a budget...Location: Rio de Janeiro. Nature of the event: art performances, booths, demos...
any suggestion it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What lens(es) are you using now? What make them insufficient for this event shoot?

Comment: I would get nothing less than the Nikon 200mm f/2G AF-S ED VR II. Done.

Comment: f/8 and be there!

Comment: I would buy <insert any lens you want>.  Outside, in bright light, just about anything works.

Comment: 18mm to xxx mm zoom made by yyy where xxx is as large as you can reasonably achieve and yyy is a maker who is as dear as you can unreasonably afford. How much is "on a budget".

Comment: Mapapalo, in order for people to provide useful information, we need more from you. Rfusca is absolutely right: any lens will do, depending on your goals. If your goals are general, then a specific answer is impossible. If your goals are more specific, we might be able to suggest some things to look for in a lens and even specific options, but we'll need something more to go on.

Answer (score 1):

As budget and flexibility seem to be the requirements then try a Sigma zoom lens. The UK range is here: http://www.sigma-imaging-uk.com/lenses/index_nikon.htm

Depending on exact budget check prices on the up to 200mm zoom lenses. Whatever you buy will be the right/wrong choice depending on the situation but only lots of practice will let you work out what you really need.

If you're really tight on budget then ebay is the place to try.